# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable

Tags: android

I am trying to dynamically set the android:src of a within an tag of a LayerList drawable.

To do so, I need to get access to the tag, but it keeps failing with:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f090142}
```

Here is the LayerList drawable portion:

```
<item android:id="@+id/my_item_id" 
    android:left="35dip" 
    android:right="0dip"
    android:top="0dip"
    android:bottom="50dip">
    <bitmap android:id="@+id/my_bitmap_id" android:gravity="left"/>
</item>
```

And here is the code:

```
Resources r = view.getResources(); 
Drawable drawable = r.getDrawable(myDrawableId); 
// it abends on this next line 
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) r.getDrawable(R.id.my_item_id); 
// this is where I want to set the id of the drawable to use in the bitmap 
ld.setDrawableByLayerId(myDrawableId, drawable);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, I tried a project clean: it didn't make any change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok when you call getDrawable it needs to refer to one of the drawables in your drawable folders.  I am not sure what my_item_id is, but if it is a drawable try

```
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) r.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_item_id);
```

Comment: my_item_id is the android:id attribute for the <item> tag (please see the xml snippet above), which I think is considered a Drawable. What my complete goal is to dynamically set the drawable that I use in the <bitmap> tag: it's id value is stored in 'myDrawableId' in this case. So I define a Drawable for myDrawableid (that work's fine), but I'm having the problem trying to set that to be what you can hard-code as 'android:src' in the <bitmap> tag.

Comment: ok if you are trying to do a layerlist from what I understand that needs to be in one of the drawable folders.  Review the following link for more clarification.  You also don't have a src for the bitmap which is incorrect from what I can tell.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: The LayerList is in the drawable folder: the problem I'm running into is that I'm trying to set the value for the <item> <bitmap> src programatically. I think you've got the right idea about having to specify the Layerlist drawable and not the <item> tag id when I do the getDrawable. I'll work with that and post any additional info I find. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That was it excactly, MikeIsrael. Thanks! The LayerDrawable needs to reference the LayerList.xml file. The setDrawableByLayerId needs to reference the id of the layer within the LayerDrawable as the first parm (R.id.my_item_id), the 2nd parm is the id of the Drawable you want placed in the layer. You don't need to specify an id for the <bitmap> tag.