# Resource cannot be found, No identifier for missing item

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-resources

I looked at this question however, it did not help solve my problem:

- [Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376537/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable)

I'm using ActionBarSherlock (version 4.4) within my app for compatibility in older versions.  My app runs perfect on 4.1.2 but it crashes on 2.3.3.  The app runs all the way up to the point of `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);`  then it crashes after that.  I cannot figure out what is causing it to crash on older versions.  I have a feeling that it is because it is trying to use something that doesn't exist in that version however, I cannot pinpoint what it is using. Does anyone see any code that seems wrong?

The error in the logcat:
`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}`

**Logcat Error**

```
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  ... 35 more
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:344)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:337)
08-15 21:01:04.967: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  ... 38 more
```

**styles.xml from values folder:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Java file**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG,"Set Content View");

        mTitle = (String) getTitle();  
        ChemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chemistrycalcstrings);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, ChemTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG,"Set Display Home");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG,"Set Home Button");
        Log.d(TAG,"Setting ActbarDrawerToggle");
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, 
                mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                getSherlock().dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                Log.d(TAG,"Drawer CLosing");
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                getSherlock().dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                Log.d(TAG,"Drawer Opening");
            }
        };
        Log.d(TAG,"Set ActbarDrawerToggle");
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        Log.d(TAG,"Set ActbarDrawerToggle Listener");

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            selectItem(0);
        }
}

private void selectItem(int position){

    SherlockFragment frag = new TestFrament();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(TestFrament.ITEM_SEL, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, frag).commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(ChemTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I went through and commented out all the parts that involved the listview `mDrawerList` and the application fired right up with a working actionbar just no listview in the drawer.

Layout activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

test_fragment_layout.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragTextSherlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="32dp" />
```

TestFragment.java

```
public class TestFrament extends SherlockFragment {
    public static final String ITEM_SEL = "item_selected";
    private TextView fragtv;

    public TestFrament() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment_layout, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ITEM_SEL);
        fragtv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragTextSherlock);
        fragtv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to open and close the drawer without crashing? (without selecting an item)

Comment: A suggestion for much smoother flow when closing the drawer, add a global variable that holds the drawer position, so your 'DrawerItemClickListener' will just have 'currentPosition = position' then 'mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerView);' then add 'selectItem(currentPosition);' to your drawer closed, also remove 'mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);' from select item. I would also suggesting adding some code to check if the selected item is the same as the previous position to keep resource usage down

Comment: I can open and close the drawer if the listview is not present in the code.  If the listview is in the code, then the app crashes on listview.layoutchildren() (part of the android source).  So it crashes before I can do anything

Comment: can you post your layout xml?

Comment: and the TestFragment code?

Comment: @adefran83 I have added them

Comment: i dont see anything odd, do you have any pictures in it? or just text?

Comment: what color code is #111? (dont have android studio in front of me to see)

Comment: @adefran83 look at my answer down below.  I already answered it, thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the compiler did not tell me that I was using items that were not part of the compatiabiliy and were not avaliable in 2.3.3

Look at the lines I had to remove:

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" <-Removed
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" <-Removed
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/> <-Removed
```

Comment: that makes sense, i use the action bar/nav drawer combo but since my app requires 4.0.4+ i didn't have to worry about compatibility

Comment: Thanks! On 2.3.7 it was enough to remove `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` to make app work.

Answer (score 5):

To support lower versions, instead of removing the following three parameters,

```
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" 
  android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

You can actually **replace** them with equivalent values/resources.

The equivalent values can be obtained from
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Now,

- **a)** `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"`
- **b)**

  1. Download a selector from 
     https://github.com/habzy/Test0011_DialerPad/blob/master/res/drawable/list_item_activated_background.xml
  2. In the above project browse the resources in hdpi,mdpi etc and get files named **list_activated_holo.9.png**
  3. Finally

  `android:background="@drawable/activated_background_holo_dark"`
- **c)** From the equivalent values obtained , we know that  **listPreferredItemHeightSmall** is 48dip

  `android:minHeight="48dip"`

Answer (score 1):

This is often occur due to unavailability of a drawable resource in res folder. Some times you just copy the drawable from other directory to you project's drawable folder, but forget to add this drawable from IDE's project explorer.