# Android strange resources$notfoundexception on emulator 2.3.3

Tags: android, string, resources

I have declared almost 10 paragraphs about product description at String.xml file. Each description contains 10-15 lines. I have TextView to show selected product content, I am setting is content as follows.

```
 tvProductDesc.setText(getResources().getString(selectedProduct.desc));
```

selectedProduct is my object contains selected product and it has a attribute of type integer 'desc' is initialised with corresponding value at String.xml

eg:- product1.desc=R.string.prd1;

Textview showing the content at higher end emulator, but when running the application at emulator 2.3.3, I am getting android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception for last few products, its  working for first few produts.

Comment: try to set text directly like `tvProductDesc.setText(selectedProduct.desc);`

Answer (score 1):

`setText()` has and overloaded method that takes an `int` as argument which should represent the id of the string resource.

When you do: `product1.desc=R.string.prd1;` you actually initialize `product1.desc` with the resource id (which is an int), not the actual string.

As a result `getResources().getString(selectedProduct.desc)` returns an `int` which the `setText()` method things it is the id of a string resource, it tries to find it, but doesn't succeed and throws ResourceNotFoundException.

To fix this, read the actual string when initializing the product, eg.:
`product1.desc=getString(R.string.prd1);`

Comment: then how its working at higher end emulators and also working for first few items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in generated String id clean your project and rebuild first or check perticular String id.

Comment: I checked the String id, its defined in the String.xml and in R.java file.

Answer (score 0):

Probe directly with

```
tvProductDesc.setText(getString(R.string.prd1));
```

to discard any errors in your `selectedProduct` object. If the line above works, check how you are populating that object.

Comment: Could you post the XML code for the strings that are causing the error?

Comment: its paragraph defined with string names prd1,prd2 etc.

Comment: But maybe some character is not allowed in 2.3, like in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18281422/1612432