# App crashing when click to update edit text field (crashing from TextWatcher?)

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

My app is crashing when the user clicks on an edit text field to update the entry. However, it doesn't crash when the field is blank and is being filled out the first time.

I believe I've narrowed down this down to the faulty code (in textwatcher code below) - however I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm further confused after looking at the stack trace - which appears to point to a missing drawable - but I can't see how these two are related. The stack trace is below as well.

Any help here would be appreciated! Please if you can give code examples on what I should try rather than just concepts it would help. Thanks in advance

Code in savesession.java

```
add_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Is_Valid_Person_Name(add_name);
    }
});
```

/* Copied in in response to comments for this code */

```
 public void Is_Valid_Person_Name(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException 
 {
    if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) 
    {
        edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
        valid_name = null;
    } else if (!edt.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) 
    {
      edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
      valid_name = null;
    } else {
      valid_name = edt.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Relevant section of stack trace:

```
09-27 00:09:11.295  13910-13910/com.yodalabs.buddhabreath E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception    dispatching input event.
09-27 00:09:11.295  13910-13910/com.yodalabs.buddhabreath D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-27 00:09:11.305  13910-13910/com.yodalabs.buddhabreath W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41841898)
09-27 00:09:11.345  13910-13910/com.yodalabs.buddhabreath E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f090001 a=1 r=0x7f090001}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:206)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:190)
```

savesession.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Comment"
    android:inputType="textPersonName">
</EditText>
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>
    <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>

</style>


<style name="your_new_text_appearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/rounded_corner_popupmenu</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/purple06</item>
</style>


    <color name="blue01">#0099CC</color>
    <color name="blue02">#079DD0</color>
```

settings.java

```
// In OnCreate 
CyclepopupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.settings_breathcycle));
CyclepopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 11, Menu.NONE, "5,0,5,0");
CyclepopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 12, Menu.NONE, "5,3,5,3 (default)");
CyclepopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 13, Menu.NONE, "5,5,5,5");
CyclepopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 14, Menu.NONE, "7,5,7,5");
CyclepopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 15, Menu.NONE, "9,5,9,5");
CyclepopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 16, Menu.NONE, "12,5,12,5");
// In body
public void showMenuCycle(View view){
   CyclepopupMenu.show();
}
```

Comment: why `Is_Valid_Person_Name(add_name);` ?

Comment: Show your `Is_Valid_Person_Name` method.

Comment: I've just added the Is_Valid_Person_Name method to the post...

Comment: I think some things going wrong in xml can you please post xml code ?

Comment: Just added the relevant xml code,

Comment: I just tested this with removing the call to Is_Valid_Person_Name - get the same error. Also kaushik tested the textwatcher code and said that was ok for him... so where to next? I'm totally stumped by this..

Comment: can you post your style and theme you've used in manifest for the same activity. Actually it seems some version related issue mainly in honeycomb..

Comment: MOSO - Ive now posted the style and theme

Answer (score 1):

Hi update your  **Is_Valid_Person_Name** method code with this code . It really helps you.

```
public void Is_Valid_Person_Name(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException 
    {
    Drawable warning = (Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    warning.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, warning.getIntrinsicWidth(), warning.getIntrinsicHeight()));
       if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) 
       {
           edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.",warning);
           valid_name = null;
       } 
       else if (!edt.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) 
       {
         edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.",warning);
         valid_name = null;
       } else {
         valid_name = edt.getText().toString();
       }
   }
```

change the drawable icon according to you.

Comment: I just tried this code (thanks) but I am still getting the same crash and the stack trace is the same as before, any other ideas?

Comment: try using default theme , don't customize it Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Thanks Droid_Lover, MOSO and kaushik for your help in sorting this out. It was the styles.xml that was causing the problem.  When editing existing text - a small drawable appears to show where in the text you are editing - this drawable doesn't appear when typing in text for the first time. I see this small drawable almost everyday when using my phone (cut and pasting text, editing txts etc) but I didn't make that connection here.

Comment: After going back to standard theme (removing custom theme) it works now. I'll need t figure out how to customize my theme without messing this drawable up going forward.

Comment: @OmahaNebrasca : it was clear from the exception that the resource was missing as the exception said about the style mishandling. Also try searching about the exceptions too you will definitely get the idea what the problem could be. This stack site is a wonderful place where you'll find most the problematic stuff ppl have already faced. We are targeting new questions(brain eater kinda) rather than seeing repeatedly the same questions.

Comment: @MOSO it was not clear to me nor the others that were trying to help me initially. I did try searching and looked at numerous posts on this website over a couple days before posting my own question. Not sure what you are saying here - should I find another forum to post questions like this and share how I resolve issues that Ive faced? Can you point me to another question where another user was facing a problem manifesting itself in the same way?

Comment: @OmahaNebrasca : Nope its indeed the right place to search your queries. What i meant was just google the exception line and woo we see lot many ppl hv already been to this problem see yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278386/resource-cannot-be-found-no-identifier-for-missing-item . However this person has written a page on this :D http://karim-ouda.blogspot.in/2013/11/androidcontentresresourcesnotfoundexcep.html :P

Comment: @MOSO - thanks I'll do that next time. These issues are always so easy to understand after they have been solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can call like this : `Is_Valid_Person_Name(s.toString());` for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Because `add_name` is an `EditText`. You should set `String` in `EditText` and what is the type of parameter in this method `Is_Valid_Person_Name(param)` is it `EditText` or `String` check that.

Comment: The Is_Valid_Person_Name methods perfectly for new entries.. It is only when I click to update an value already in the edit text field that causes the crash. The stack trace output is confusing me even more - what does a drawable have to do with this?

Comment: @OmahaNebrasca : textwatcher code is ok I have tested it u have problem in other portion

Comment: Ok thanks kausik - you tested it with updating text right (not just new text)? Thanks again. Yeah, I'm still baffled by the reference to the drawable in the stack trace,

Comment: in which device u r testing ?

Comment: I'm testing on Galaxy S3, Android 4.3

Comment: have u used any `PopupWindow` if yes post xml

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by removing the `customization to the theme`. I believe the culprit was the `customization` to `popupWindowStyle`.

When editing existing text in a edittext box - a popup appears to show you where in the text field you are updating. If custom style mess up the appearance of this popup then you get the app crashes that I was getting.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>
    <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>
    -->
</style>
```